# how to place a card to the bottom with jetpack compose？

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to place a card on top of a map view. And I want the card to locate close to the bottom.

I used a box layout and put the map and card into it. But I only know contentAlignment to arrange the inside components. Now I have the card dispalyed above the map centrally. How can I fix it? What kind of layout setup is required?

what I want

[image: 1]

what I get

[image: 2]

My code.

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    MapScreen()
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(380.dp)
            .height(350.dp),
        elevation = 10.dp,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)
    )
    {
        Column(
            Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        )
        {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Recomendationm(indicatorValue = value)
            Text("Here")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Card` you can use the **`align`** modifier to override the `contentAlignment` defined by the parent `Box`:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    //..
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(380.dp)
            .height(350.dp)
            .align(BottomCenter),
    //...
}
```

As described in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).align(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment)):

> Pull the content element to a specific `Alignment` within the `Box`. This alignment **will have priority over** the `Box`'s `alignment` parameter.

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer to make sure the issue is marked as resolved (click on the tick).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
If you are using only Card (which is not wrapped under Box) then 
.align(alignment = Alignment.BottomCenter) gives expected behaviour.